# Phonegap (Android) - database changeVersion not functioning

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

If I take a database object (db) and open it with the command

```
var db = window.openDatabase("phr", "", "Cognovant PHR", 25000000);
// This should open whatever database is created, otherwise spawn one with a blank
// version number ("")
```

and then later do:

```
db.changeVersion(db.version, "2"); // Update database to version 2
console.log(db.version); //Should return "2", instead returns previous version of database
```

This code, line-for-line works flawlessly (almost better than I had hoped) on iOS, but constantly fails to change the database version on Android.

If there's some better way to do this, or some alternative way that needs done on Android, I would be greatly appreciative of the information.

Comment: Upon further research, this issue only shows up on Android version 2.3.x (gingerbread). But i need to make this work for Gingerbread as well, so any help is still appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple to solve.

Simply change the 2 argument version of db.changeVersion to the 3 argument version. Example:

`db.changeVersion(db.version, "2", function () {console.log("foobar")});`

And it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This problem also occurs in Android 2.2.

> 09-28 07:15:14.954: E/Web Console(280): TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: DOM Exception 17: The type of an object was incompatible with the expected type of the parameter associated to the object. at file:///android_asset/www/devbar/03%20db.js:158

The only solution I see is to workaround with my own version management.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below link, describes the way to implement the database Version control.

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/safarijsdatabaseguide/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase.html

i am able to do success operation with all 2.3.x devices, but with 4.x.x android device getting issue like 'unable to call method changeVersion' and saying method is undefined.

for time being i am using code as below,

```
if (db.changeVersion) {
    db.changeVersion(oldVer, curVer, upgradeTableStructure, errorHandler, successDataHandler);
} else {
    createTableStructure(db);//If Not exist for first time for 4.x.y devices
    console.log('version changes not possible in this browser version.');
}
```

but this is not the right solution for the Current Problem, please suggest some solution.